# Is it possible to use styles from an Angular service in scss?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I have a change-color.service.ts that has the following:

```
public defaultStyles = {
    firstDesignBackgroundColor: '#a31329',
    firstDesignFontColor: '#ffffff',
    secondDesignBackgroundColor: '#d1cfcfff',
    secondDesignFontColor: '#000000'
  };
```

now I will like to add to my style.scss for the statement

```
:host ::ng-deep th span#optimize-checkbox-header .mat-checkbox label.mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-inner-container.mat-checkbox-inner-container-no-side-margin .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border: 2px solid #fff !important;
}
```

replace the `#fff` with `firstDesignFontColor` from the `change-service`. Do you know how I can create this dependency? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Why don't u create classes with your each condition? from service get your class name and assign class to element depends on the condition.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a way to realize it with css variables that I will post here as a second answer.

You can change css variables from JavaScript code, so if you use variables for your class like this simplified example:

```
:root {
  --bg-color: red;
}

.test {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

then you can change this from your ChangeColorService

```
interface Colors {
  background: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ChangeColorService {
    colors$ = new BehaviorSubject<Colors>({ background: 'red' });

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

    change(colors: Colors) {
      const root = this.document.documentElement;
      root.style.setProperty('--bg-color', colors.background);
      this.colors$.next(colors);
    }
}
```

Full example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-css-variable?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I just read trough your first answer and was like, what about css variables and than i saw your second answer :D

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible. What is possible, is to use style bindings.

```
class YourComponent {
    styles: any;
    constructor(private color: ChangeColor) {}
    ngOnInit() { this.styles = this.color.defaultStyles; }
}
```

```
  <div [style.background-color]="styles.firstDesignBackgroundColor"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I did that too. There are scss classes in my code that I can't change via the template (like in my example). Thought you could somehow import the service into the scss file and then call the variable at the appropriate place.

Comment: @and.neo2020 I just realized that there might be a way for you with css variables. See my other answer.